# StandardError and StandardOutput are empty when executing an exe

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, process, exe

I am trying to make a simple winform gui just for myself

When running bbmod.exe in cmd manually it will write an error and some text, or if you provide the right arguments some success text.

But when running the exe (by double clicking on it) It will just flash for a milisecond.
The same happens when i try to run it thorugh this process, and also the output streams are empty, both standard and error.

```cs
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\tools\BBMOD\stann_gui\BBMOD_launch.bat";

p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

p.WaitForExit();

textBoxLog.Text = output;
```

I've tried both standardOutput and standardError
I've also tried making a .bat file running the same .exe with /k argument (makes it not close immediately)

But there all that's returned from the outputs is the text from the bat file.

I've also just ignored trying to write to my own textbox, and just have the bat file make the console window appear with text instead. But i'd prefer to get the output within the program

Comment: Is the exe written by you?

Comment: @shingo  it is not

Comment: Then you need to confirm with the author, check Damien's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088894/when-run-a-program-in-c-all-the-messages-go-to-the-standard-output-but-the-st

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick check with a sample bat file and this should work.
I am using cmd to run the .bat file

```
 Process process = new Process();
 
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
 {
     FileName = "cmd.exe", // Use cmd.exe to run the batch file
     Arguments = "/c test.bat", // Pass the batch file as an argument to cmd.exe
     RedirectStandardOutput = true, 
     RedirectStandardError = true, 
     UseShellExecute = false, 
     CreateNoWindow = true 
 };

 process.StartInfo = startInfo;
 process.Start();

 string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

 process.WaitForExit();

 Console.WriteLine("Standard Output:");
 Console.WriteLine(output);

 Console.WriteLine("Standard Error:");
 Console.WriteLine(error);
```

test.bat

```
@echo off

echo This is standard output
echo This is standard error >&2
```